# C++: Issue overloading I/O operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, ostream, istream

I'm currently finding it impossible to fix an occurrence of infinite recursion in my code.

I have the following header that defines the `Proces` class:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Proces {
    std::string name;
    int maxWaitTime;
    int timeToFinish;
    int timeWaited;
    int timeProcessed;

public:
    Proces(std::string n, int mwt = 1, int ttf = 1) :name(n), maxWaitTime(mwt), timeToFinish(ttf), timeWaited(0), timeProcessed(0) {}
    bool process(int a = 1) { timeProcessed += a; return isComplete(); }
    bool isComplete() { return timeProcessed >= timeToFinish; }
    bool wait(int a = 1) { timeWaited += a;return maxWaitReached(); }
    bool maxWaitReached() { return maxWaitTime <= timeWaited; }
    friend bool operator<(const Proces& a, const Proces& b);
    friend bool operator>(const Proces& a, const Proces& b);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Proces& a);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, const Proces& a);
};
```

Then, for the implementation of the operators, I have:

```
 #include "proces.h"

    bool operator<(const Proces & a, const Proces & b)
    {
        if (a.timeWaited != b.timeWaited)
            return a.timeWaited < b.timeWaited;
        else
            return a.maxWaitTime < b.maxWaitTime;
    }

    bool operator>(const Proces & a, const Proces & b)
    {
        return ! (a < b);
    }

    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & output, const Proces & a)
    {
        output << a.naziv << " MWT:" << a.maxWaitTime << " TTC:" << a.timeToFinish << " WT:" << a.timeWaited << " TP:" << a.timeProcessed;
        return output;
    }

    std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & input,Proces & a)
    {
        input >> a.name >> a.maxWaitTime >> a.timeToFinish;
        a.timeWaited = 0;
        a.timeProcessed = 0;
        return input;
    }
```

This lead to two (as far as I know unrelated) problems:

1. Use of the output operator lead to said infinite recursion happening
2. The code itself cannot be compiled without commenting out the implementation 
   of the input operator as it claims the fields of the class are inaccessible 
   in spite of being a friend of the class

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)  E0265   member "Proces::name" (declared at line 4 of "[project path]\proces.h") is inaccessible aspdz2  [project path]\proces.cpp

Here is the main function (the < and > operators work as intended):

```
#include "proces.h"

int main() {
    Proces a{ "Glorious prces",1,2 };
    Proces b{ "Glorious prces2",2,2 };

    if (a < b)std::cout << "A is lesser" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "B is lesser" << std::endl;

    if (a > b)std::cout << "A is greater" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "B is greater" << std::endl;
    b.wait(-1);
    if (a < b)std::cout << "A is lesser" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "B is lesser" << std::endl;

    //Infinite recursion happens here:
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: std::string name;
It is not public. This is why you get an error.

Comment: In header input operator has const param, in implementation it doesn't.

Comment: You have a typo in the `operator>>` friend declaration. Remove the `const` from the second argument.

Comment: Yeah, the const thing was one of the mistakes, but after fixing it, i get "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2678 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion) [project path]\proces.cpp  
"

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the reason for the

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error (active) E0265 member "Proces::name" (declared at line 4 of "[project path]\proces.h") is inaccessible aspdz2 [project path]\proces.cpp

error was due to the accidental inclusion of the `const` keyword in the declaration of the `>>` operator;
The recursion on the other hand was happening because I forgot to`#include<string>`